# How to change the router history in a functional component using react-redux

Tags: react-redux, react-hooks, browser-history, connected-react-router

I'm trying to migrate a code base from a `class` component to a `functional` component, but when I do that my history (`browserHistory`) and the redirects stop working.

I don't know if it's in the way I'm using `useEffect`, or forcing the `history.push` ? But I get a `Warning: You cannot change <Router history>`   on `Router` and `Connected Router`. I get the right values from the `state` and `redux` and I can see the changes on the location when I `console.log` it is just that `history.push` that doesn't happen.

I'm using `react-redux` and `connected-react-router`.

What might the problem be?

**Use case**: Facebook API loads, when user signs in with Facebook, the user is redirected to another page.

This code works: `class Component (old code)`

```js
class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    
        this.facebookInterval = undefined;
        this.history = createBrowserHistory();
    
        this.state = {
          hasFB: false,
          error: false,
        };
      }
    
      /**
       * Load the Facebook SDK
       *
       * @return {void}
       */
      componentDidMount() {
    
        this.facebookInterval = setInterval(() => {
          if (window.FB !== undefined) {
            this.setState({
              hasFB: true,
            });
    
            clearInterval(this.facebookInterval);
          }
        }, 100);
    
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
          window.FB.init({
            appId: process.env.REACT_APP_NEW_MESSENGER_APP_ID,
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v3.3',
          });
        };
    
        (function (d, s, id) {
          var js,
            fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
          }
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src =
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?xfbml=1&version=v9.0&appId=' +
            process.env.REACT_APP_NEW_MESSENGER_APP_ID;
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
      }
    
    
      // [NOTE]: This works when using the class component
      // the redirect happens
    
      componentWillUpdate = (nextProps, nextState) => {
        console.log('nextProps.redirect', nextProps.redirect)
        console.log('nextProps', nextProps)
        console.log('nextState', nextState)
    
        if (nextProps.redirect !== undefined && nextProps.redirect !== '/') {
          this.history.push(nextProps.redirect);
        }
      };
    
      render() {
        const { t } = this.props;
    
        if (this.state.hasFB) {
          return (
            <>
              <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
                <ConnectedRouter history={this.history}>{routes}</ConnectedRouter>
              </Elements>
            </>
          );
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      }
    }
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    
      let isLoading = state.siteR.isLoading ? 'open' : 'close';
    
    
      let data = {
        redirect: state.siteR.location,
        isLoading: isLoading,
    
        user: state.userR[state.userR.id],
        id: state.userR.id,
      };
    
      if (state.userR[state.userR.id] !== undefined) {
        data.models = state.userR[state.userR.id].models;
      }
    
      return data;
    };
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        // ommited_code
      };
    };
    
    export default compose(
      connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
      withTranslation(),
    )(App);
```

Same code, but on a functional component (**new code**)

```js
  const App = (props) => {
    
      console.log('props', props)
      // console.log('props.redirect', props.redirect)
      
      const [hasFB, setHasFB] = useState(false)
      const [error, setError] = useState(false)
      const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(props.redirect)
    
    
      const history = createBrowserHistory()
      let facebookInterval = undefined
    
      const {t} = useTranslation()
    
      const initializeFacebook = () => {
        facebookInterval = setInterval(() => {
          if (window.FB !== undefined) {
            setHasFB(true)
            clearInterval(facebookInterval);
          }
        }, 100);
    
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
          window.FB.init({
            appId: process.env.REACT_APP_NEW_MESSENGER_APP_ID,
            autoLogAppEvents: true,
            xfbml: true,
            version: 'v3.3',
          });
        };
    
        (function (d, s, id) {
          var js,
            fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
          }
          js = d.createElement(s);
          js.id = id;
          js.src =
            'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?xfbml=1&version=v9.0&appId=' +
            process.env.REACT_APP_NEW_MESSENGER_APP_ID;
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
      }
    
    
    // [NOTE]:  I get the right values from props.redirect
    // and  the state
    // the redirect just doesnt happen
    const handleRedirect = () => {
    
      if (props.redirect !== undefined && props.redirect !== '/') {
        console.log('redirect on setRedirect', redirect)
        setRedirect(history.push(props.redirect))
      }
    }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        initializeFacebook()
        handleRedirect()
        console.log('redirect on setRedirect', redirect)
      }, [])
    
    
      if (hasFB) {
        return (
          <>
            <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
              <ConnectedRouter history={history}>{routes}</ConnectedRouter>
            </Elements>
          </>
        );
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
    
    
    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    
      let isLoading = state.siteR.isLoading ? 'open' : 'close';
      let showModelSelect = state.modelR.showModelSelect ? 'open' : 'close';
      let showModelAdd = state.modelR.showModelAdd ? 'open' : 'close';
    
      let data = {
        redirect: state.siteR.location,
        isLoading: isLoading,
    
        user: state.userR[state.userR.id],
        id: state.userR.id,
      };
    
      if (state.userR[state.userR.id] !== undefined) {
        data.models = state.userR[state.userR.id].models;
      }
    
      return data;
    };
    
    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return {
        // ommited_code
      };
    };
    
    export default compose(
      connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
      withTranslation(),
    )(App);
```

The routes I'm trying to switch to/from

```js
const routes =  (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <SentryRoute exact path='/' component={UserLogin} />

      <SentryRoute exact path='/user' component={Profile} />

        {/* // omited_code */}
    </Switch>
  </div>
)

export default routes;
```

Comment: use useHistory instead of createBrowserHistory to access history. Create it only once in topmost component

Comment: This might help. https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, it looks like you might be able to use the additional params in the `connect` function.

```
import { push } from 'connected-react-router';

/* code stuffs */
props.push('/home');

export default connect(null, { push })(Component);
```

https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#with-react-redux